# Error installing RabbitMQ in ubuntu14.04

Tags: 14.04, dpkg, mysql, rabbitmq

I am getting this error while trying to install RabbitMQ using the command

```
sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server
```

> You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
>   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not installable
>    rabbitmq-server : Depends: socat but it is not installable
>   E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

What should I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808909/simple-way-to-install-rabbitmq-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Try doing what the error message says. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

(with no packages)

From the output of `man apt-get`

```
-f, --fix-broken  
    Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place. 
    This option, when used with install/remove, can omit any packages  
    to permit APT to deduce a likely solution.
```